# How to pass value in AlertDialog.Builder setSingleChoiceItems?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i develop in android app.my problem is i used alert dialog box and i pass value in setsinglechoiceitems. but i coundn't pass the value . my sourcecode below .please give me solution.

```
public void AlertBoxShow(int position) {
        int pos=position;
        Log.v("log_tag"," position ::"+pos);
        final CharSequence[] items = { " 5 ", " 10 ", " 15 "};

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,  int which) {

                        switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            //updateStatus(pos);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            // Your code when first option seletced
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // Your code when 2nd option seletced
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            // Your code when 3rd option seletced
                            break;


                        }

                    }



                });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Bhavesh Thanks For the reply but my problem is solved just add final int pos=position;  it's fine works.